# К чему относится придаточное предложение?

Tags: спп, придаточное-предложение

*Основная масса грамот связана с делами о государственных податях, что типично для торгового центра, каким был Новгород.*

Здесь "что" начинает придаточное предложение? Если так, то от какого слова оно зависит?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В данном случае это придаточное присоединительное. Придаточная часть здесь присоединяется союзом *что* и относится ко всему главному предложению.

Ср.: Полжизни он провёл в путешествиях, **что не могло не оставить отпечаток на его личности.**

Мой отец отстроил дом на даче собственными руками, **что требовало большой кропотливости и умения.**